# Can this idea be materialized to a useful ad?

Tags: discussion, community

In the Apple.SE site, something brought my attention, it's an amazing ad that counts in real time the number of bounties on questions and their total value: https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1882/community-promotion-ads-2014#1884

Could this ad ever be adopted by the Math.SE community?

But more importantly, how could it be useful?

---

As usual on Meta, upvote=agree

downvote=disagree

---

**EDIT:** The ad shows excellent results for its first appearance:

- $^1$ Clicks per day: $22.56$
- Total clicks: $203$

$^1$ Which are higher than $11$ out of $12$ ads.

Comment: This would not be useful for me. But that's just me.

Comment: It quite likely _could_ be used.  I copied the [source](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/revisions/0c649f0d-72fb-46c3-a6f6-95d47c9da580/view-source) over to our 2014 Community Ads thread, and it seemed to display properly. (I didn't actually submit an answer, but the preview seemed to work fine.)  Would be useful for the site? I guess that's what votes would decide.

Comment: **pretty** cool. It also works when you put it in your ["About me"](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/19341/draks) section...

Comment: For the code:  `[![Current Ask Different bounties][1]][2]

  [1]: http://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/bounty.png
  [2]: http://math.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured`

Comment: Ye gods and little fishes but that thing is obtrusively ugly!

Comment: I don't see the point. The information is not hard to obtain, and it doesn't fluctuate enough that one needs to track it minute-to-minute.  So I don't understand what the ad is for, except as a technology demonstration.

Comment: It is so large it broke my screen.

Comment: @copper.hat The add works perfectly even if it is very large (see  Apple.SE).

Comment: How did you get the number of views? I think you can accept the answer...

Comment: @draks... From the stats: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/ads/display/11920

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several reasons to try:

- it will add some variety to the sidebar
- the design is nice (also optimized for high-density pixel displays)
- it would bring more occasional expert visitors  (such as MO users) to the featured tab. People used to SE interface  eventually tune out that small red rectangle with a number on it; this ad is more likely to catch  their eye
- the last but not least: it's a bit like  hacking the site (getting around the hosted-on-imgur restriction for ads), which is  a  fun thing to do.

And besides, approving or disapproving  ads is something that the community does in the thread containing them. Posting an ad there is merely a nomination.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications you made in your post, and yes, I shared it on the Meta ads 2014 thread: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/12008/93957